# command working with cmd but not from python code

Tags: python, subprocess, avconv

I am trying to convert a test.mp4 file to test.wav from python code using avconv. I am able to convert the test.mp4 to test.wmv using cmd line but when i run the same command from python its giving me following error :

line 103, in get_message_audio
    subprocess.call(cmdline)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The code i am using from python file is :

cmdline = ['avconv',
           '-i',
           'test.mp4',
           '-vn',
           '-f',
           'wav',
           'test.wav']

subprocess.call(cmdline)

But when i run the same command from cmd it successfully runs and save the test.wav file.

cmd line =  avconv -i test.mp4 -f wav test.wav

Note: I have added avconv to system variable. The python file and test.mp4 is in the same directory. I am running the cmd from the same directory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is not finding the `avconv` executable.  I would suggest that you use the full absolute path to `avconv` in your command in Python.  Another thing you can try is using a shell, by adding `shell=True` to your `subprocess.call()` call.

In other words, do this and see if it helps:

```
cmdline = [r'\full\path\to\avconv', '-i', 'test.mp4', '-vn', '-f', 'wav', 'test.wav']
subprocess.call(cmdline, shell=True)
```

I don't think it's the input file it can't find.  It doesn't seem to be getting that far.  At the point that `subprocess.call(cmdline)` is failing, `test.mp4` and `test.wav` are just strings being passed to `avconv`.

My guess is that `avconv` isn't in the PATH of the environment in which Python is running the command.  `shell=True` might help that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the location of the file is not your current working directory. Add

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

To check where your script looks for the files.

If that’s not the right location, you can use

```
os.chdir(„your/file/directory“)
```